# GitHub GraphQL API: Is a user suspended?

Tags: github-api, github-enterprise, github-graphql

Working on GitHub Enterprise Server 3.8:

My user is no "site-admin", but on the GitHub Web-UI I see on a users profile if the user was suspended:

[image]

I also see that information, when I do a [REST call](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.8/rest/users/users#get-a-user):

[image]

However, if I try to to access the same information via the GitHub GraphQL API (using the same token as with the REST call) I get an error:

```
query FindUsers ($myQuery: String!) {
    search (query: $myQuery type: USER first: 10) {
        userCount
        nodes {
            ... on User {
                login
                name
                email
                suspendedAt
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> "Your token has not been granted the required scopes to execute this query. The 'suspendedAt' field requires one of the following scopes: ['site_admin'], but your token has only been granted the: ['admin:org', 'repo', 'user:email'] scopes. Please modify your token's scopes at: [https://github.developer.allianz.io/settings/tokens."](https://github.developer.allianz.io/settings/tokens.%22)

The error is the same regardless of I perform a '[search](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.8/graphql/reference/queries#search)' or a direct '[user](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.8/graphql/reference/queries#user)' query.

As I said, I'm no `site_admin`, so I can't add that scope to my token.
But I also don't understand why I would need that scope, when I can see the information on the UI.

I'm assuming a bug in GitHub, but the question is, should I actually not see the information in the UI and on the Rest-API, or should a lesser scope be sufficient to receive it also via the GraphQL-API? (FTR: I tried `user` but it didn't work either.)

*Note:* I actually only care about the 'suspended' state. I do not need the timestamp of suspension.